# Why do Ubuntu notifications fade when I'm hovering them?

Tags: 13.04, notification

I don't understand the logic behind this. If a notification pops up and I want it to stay a little longer, I can hover it, but the notification fades, which makes it illegible. On the other hand, when I want to close it immediately, I expect it to close when I click on it, but instead it sticks even harder.

It seems like the logic is reversed here. Can it be changed ?

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#mouseover) is the design specification.

I can't find the original text to this, but as far as I can remember, the idea with the translucence on mouseover was designed so when a user needs to read what is below the bubble he/she can uncover it with the mouse pointer.

The Notify-OSD has changed a bit since this document appeared. Notably there are no more buttons on it. But the rational behind it is still the same.

However, I haven't seen a way to configure it as per your description. You would probably have to go to the source and [create your own version](http://cqlug.linux.org.au/node/23).

**EDIT**
[Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html) has an [article](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html) how to patch the Notify-OSD to be click-closeable under Ubuntu 12.04.